# Hadoop mapper constructor, when and how?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

Ok, so I tried to run my program and this error showed up:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.(..).SimpleMapReducePricing$SimplePricingMapper.()

which means that I have to initialize my mapper with a constructor, right?
So, my question is why do I have to do it, (since I haven't seen it in any example) and how can I do it in a simple (noob) way?
I am using the new api, and my piece of code is the following:

```
    public class SimplePricingMapper 
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable>
    {   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

and so on...

p.s. I saw a similar question, but I must admit that the answers confused me more. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the context of your code, but based on your exception message it seems that your `Mapper` is a embedded class (or so called `inner class`) in `SimpleMapReducePricing`.

Hadoop can not instantiate the `Mapper` without an instance of `SimpleMapReducePricing`, therefore you should define your `Mapper` class as static.

```
public static class SimplePricingMapper
```

I also suspect you have a reducer embedded into your `SimpleMapReducePricing` so you should also define it static.

Comment: Sir, you have helped me greatly. My diploma is now one day closer! Thank you.